# How to save output to a txt file

Tags: java

Quick Q

i have a loop that finds all the files in a directory, what i want to do is add a line of code into it that would write these results into a txt file, how would i best do this

current code :

```
public String FilesInFolder() {
        // Will list all files in the directory, want to create a feature on the page that can display this to the user

        String path = NewDestination;
        System.out.println("Starting searching files in directory"); // making sure it is called
        String files;
        File folder = new File(path);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {

            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
                System.out.println(files);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) and [StringWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html) together.

```
 public String FilesInFolder() throws IOException {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("file.txt");
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

    // Will list all files in the directory, want to create a feature on the page that can display this to the user

    String path = NewDestination;
    System.out.println("Starting searching files in directory"); // making sure it is called
    String files;
    File folder = new File(path);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {

        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
            sw.write(files);
            System.out.println(files);
        }
    }
    fw.write(sw.toString());
    fw.close();
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With [FileWritter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) and [BufferedWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html):

```
public String FilesInFolder() {
    // Will list all files in the directory, want to create a feature on the page that can display this to the user

    String path = NewDestination;
    System.out.println("Starting searching files in directory"); // making sure it is called
    String files;
    File folder = new File(path);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();


    File file = new File("output.txt");

    // if file doesnt exists, then create it
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {

        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
            System.out.println(files);
            bw.write(files);
        }
    }

    bw.close();
    return "";
}
```